# Ошибка переменный в pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Я пытаюсь сделать, чтобы белый квадрат двигался по полю. Для этого у меня в основном цикле есть проверка на нажатие клавиш WASD, а для координат есть две переменные: Pl_X, Pl_Y. Они задаются в самом начале программы и они глобальные. Затем я создаю player_pos = (Pl_X, Pl_Y, Pl_W, Pl_H) для удобства отрисовки белого прямоугольника. Однако Питон выдает:

```
local variable 'Pl_X' referenced before assignment
```

Вот основной код:

```
global Pl_X, Pl_Y, Pl_H, Pl_W
#window settings
WIDTH = 1000
HEIGHT = 600
FPS = 60
#player settings
Pl_W = 50
Pl_H = 70
Pl_X = 100
Pl_Y = 100
#colors
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (220, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 80, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
DARKGRAY = (40, 40, 40)
PURPLE = (120, 0, 120)
SKYBLUE = (0, 186, 255)
YELLOW = (220, 220, 0)
SANDY = (244, 164, 96)
DARKBROWN = (97, 61, 25)
DARKORANGE = (255, 140, 0)

import pygame

pygame.init()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

display = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption('Zeugs')

def run_game():
    game = True
    player_pos = (Pl_X, Pl_Y, Pl_W, Pl_H)
    while game:
        
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                quit()
             
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                    Pl_Y += 5
                if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                    Pl_Y -= 5
                if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                    Pl_X -= 5
                if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                    Pl_X += 5
            
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        #moving(keys, Pl_X, Pl_Y, Pl_W, Pl_H)

        pygame.draw.rect(display, WHITE, player_pos)
        
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(FPS)

run_game()
```

Как это починить?

Answer (score 1):

переместите строчку `global Pl_X, Pl_Y, Pl_H, Pl_W` в начало функции `run_game`

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка  `local variable 'Pl_X' referenced before assignment`

возникает здесь:

```
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                    Pl_Y += 5 <-- при попытке сложения и вычитания от переменных Pl_X, Pl_Y, Pl_H, Pl_W`
```

[Danis](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/400096/danis) дал правильный ответ.

Поскольку переменные инициализированы за пределами функции для изменения [неизменяемых](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/l-python_details_02/index.html) типов данных в python в начале функции нужно написать `global` и перечислить имена переменных которые нужно изменять.

```
def run_game():
     global Pl_X, Pl_Y, Pl_H, Pl_W
```

А в начале нужно её удалить, так как это ни на что не влияет